Measures of efficacy for one classification models on the same data set with different numbers of classes?
I am currently doing a university project in supervised learning. The variable to be predicted varies across the integers [0,100] and my supervisor suggested to split this range into different classes and train a classifier. As it is not clear how to split these values I would like to compare the outcomes of a classifier with different numbers of classes. The only measure I am aware of for classification models is the confusion matrix which is clearly not suitable for this purpose as the number of classes affects the probability of classifying a data point correctly. I'd be grateful if anyone could help me with this.
